# How to upload file to cloudinary using Node.js and Postman

Tags: node.js, heroku, postman, multer, cloudinary

I am uploading the file by Postman using Node js. Here I need to upload the file into Cloudinary. My Postman screen shot is given below:

[image]

I am providing my code below:

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var cloudinary = require('cloudinary');
cloudinary.config({ 
   cloud_name: 'sample', 
   api_key: '874837483274837', 
   api_secret: 'a676b67565c6767a6767d6767f676fe1' 
});
var storage =multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, Date.now()+'-'+file.originalname);
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage });
app.post('/api/users/save-card-file',upload.single('file'), function (req, res, next) { 

})
```

I am hosting my project in Heroku. Here I need to store that image file  into Cloudinary and get the uploaded file URL as response.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading image to Cloudinary with Node.js:

```
cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload("/home/my_image.jpg", 
function(error, result) {console.log(result)});
```

In the result object you should get the `url` and `secure_url` for the uploaded image.